# Woocommerce: deshabilitar campos direccion al seleccionar un estado/ciudad

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

estoy tratando de esconder los campos de dirección cuando se selecciona en states una opción que no es "Lima y Callao". Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora.

jQuery:

```
if($("#billing_state option:selected").val() != "Lima y Callao"){

$('#billing_address_1_field').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
});
$('#billing_address_2_field').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
});
```

}

if($("#shipping_state option:selected").val() != "Lima y Callao"){

```
$('#shipping_address_1_field').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
});
$('#shipping_address_2_field').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
$("#billing_state").on("change", function (){
 if($("#billing_state option:selected").val() != "Lima y Callao"){
  $('[id^=billing_address_]').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }else{
  $('[id^=billing_address_]').show(function(){
    $(this).addClass("validate-required");
    $(this).addClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }
});
```

Si deseas que este código funcione para el campo de Billing & Shipping state, haz las siguientes modificaciones:

```
$("[id$=state]").on("change", function (){
 $id=$(this).prop("id").split("_")[0];
 if($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "Lima y Callao"){
  $('[id^='+$id+'_address_]').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }else{
  $('[id^='+$id+'_address_]').show(function(){
    $(this).addClass("validate-required");
    $(this).addClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }
});
```

aqui te dejo un ejemplo que podrás ver como funciona si pulsas el botón `Ejecutar` (que esta mas abajo)

```js
$("[id$=state]").on("change", function (){
 $id=$(this).prop("id").split("_")[0];
 if($(this).find("option:selected").val() != "Lima y Callao"){
  $('[id^='+$id+'_address_]').hide(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }else{
  $('[id^='+$id+'_address_]').show(function(){
    $(this).addClass("validate-required");
    $(this).addClass("woocommerce-validated");
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Billing State <select name="billing_state" id="billing_state">
<option>ciudad 1</option>
<option>ciudad 2</option>
<option>ciudad 3</option>
<option>Lima y Callao</option>
</select><br>
dir1<input id="billing_address_1_field" style="display:none"><br>
dir2<input id="billing_address_2_field" style="display:none"><br>
Shipping State <select name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state">
<option>ciudad 1</option>
<option>ciudad 2</option>
<option>ciudad 3</option>
<option>Lima y Callao</option>
</select><br>
dir1<input id="shipping_address_1_field" style="display:none"><br>
dir2<input id="shipping_address_2_field" style="display:none"><br>
```

Vaya! es increíble como [jQuery](https://jquery.com) nos ayuda a desarrollar mas! escribiendo menos!.

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Hola, he usado tu código, pero al marcar  en state la opcion Lima y Callao, los campos siguen escondidos.

Comment: que extraño?... te recomiendo pruebes el ejemplo que te deje, yo ya lo he hecho y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Por casualidad lo probaste en una instalación de wordpress?

Comment: @Jorge no hace falta instalarlo, si te fijas (unas lineas mas arriba) hay un botón que dice "Ejecutar", al pulsarlo podrás probar el código que escribí.

Comment: Ya me funciono. El problema era que el billing_state detectaba las abreviaturas de las ciudades y no los nombres.

Comment: que bueno!... m alegra haberte ayudado.